# Android compile with different resources (white label)

Tags: android, compilation, continuous-integration, apk, android-resources

We have an Android project where we maintain a single code base for different customers, what will be the fastest/most efficient way to compile for different customers every time? Few options I found and my questions:

1. **writing scripts:** to replace resources folder and edit app name, version, etc.
2. **Using Android Library Projects** It is gonna be quite impractical to separate current project as Library projects, I am thinking whether it is possible to save some settings and resources files as a Library project and just import different library projects for different compilation?
3. **Storing settings and resources on a remote server** Is it possible to store resource files and some app settings (xml, constants, etc) on a remote server, and download them and replace to the app when the user first launch the apk? Where will these files be stored?

Any other options you would suggest?

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio provides a feature called "flavors" that allow you to quickly define different configurations from a single code base. I have just learned about this in the last couple of days, so I don't know a lot more than this.

Comment: Thanks. I had a quick look into studio's gradle build, found this article (http://blog.robustastudio.com/mobile-development/android/building-multiple-editions-of-android-app-gradle/) very helpful.. Is it a lot of hassle to export projects from ADT to Android studio?

Comment: @thinzar00 I have 7 different Eclipse projects for two different versions of my app (paid and free), a library for shared code, and three test projects, plus a mock app project. It took me most of a day to combine these together into a single gradle project. YMMV

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found is a post build script step.  Use a default set of resources/assets for your main build.  This is your default apk, use it for default testing.  Save the unsigned apk this builds.  Then for the customer specific APKs, open up the unsigned apk (its just a zip file), overwrite any overwritten files, then sign the new version.

This works fine so long as you don't need to change code for different customers.  It also doesn't put any unneeded assets/resources in any build, so you don't leak info to one customer about your other customers by including their files.

If you do need to change code, the best way is to do a runtime check on a variable from a settings file.  And overwrite the settings file the same way you do everything else.

As an added bonus, if you need to you can write a very fancy system that would allow the customer to upload his own files to override your defaults (including allowing them to override some of your settings), so you don't need to deal with a dozen change requests.  That requires a lot more work though.

Comment: <quote>do a runtime check on a variable from a settings file</quote>
How do we achieve this? I want to save setting files on a remote server. Is it the right approach to retrieve settings and save to sqlite?

Comment: Or save to a file, depending on the type and amount of data.

Comment: thanks. mind sharing a little bit about how you normally do "post build script step"?